# HOW TO GET QUERY IN SQL USING PHP IN SQL TIGGERING

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

This is my code my $sql variable didn't give query plese help me for this I try this but I couldn't please help me with that

```
<?php 
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "finger");
    $f= "";
    $l= "";
    $sql = "CREATE TRIGGER `ersdmmmmecv` AFTER INSERT ON `event` FOR EACH ROW  SELECT fname,Lname INTO $f,$l  FROM user WHERE id=NEW.id;"
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
?>
```

Comment: If the query fails, `$result` will be `FALSE` and you can see more information about *why* the query failed by doing `echo mysqli_error($connect);`. If you add that, what is the error message?

Comment: it shows  cannot return value in trigger'

Comment: Is it possible the select can return more than 1 row - if so use limit (use limit anyway)

Comment: Well, that is correct. Triggers cannot return values. Triggers are used to manipulate data (i.e., perform an UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE query when something happens). It doesn't really make sense to run a SELECT query when a trigger happens, because nothing is going to receive those rows.

Comment: how I Select  columns and get the data using trigger?

Comment: You cannot. That is not what a trigger is for. Apart from that, PHP and MySQL are two separate things. `SELECT column INTO php_variable` is never going to work because MySQL does not know about the PHP variables.

Comment: is there way to do same as this?

Comment: how I get it using php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Trigger Solution

```
   <?php 
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "finger");
      $sql1 = "CREATE TRIGGER `ersdmmmmecv` AFTER INSERT ON `event` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO res (fres,lres) VALUES SELECT fname,Lname   FROM user WHERE id=NEW.id;";
       
      $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1); 
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM res;";
       
             
       if( !( $selectRes = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)  ) ){
        echo 'Retrieval of data from Database Failed - #';
      }else{
        ?>
 
     <table border="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>fName</th>
                <th>lname</th>
                
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                if( mysqli_num_rows( $selectRes )==0 ){
                    $print_output= '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';
                }else{
                    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $selectRes ) ){
                    $print_output="<tr><td>{$row['fres']}</td><td>{$row['lres']}</td></tr>\n";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>

            <?php
                 try
                 {
                     $fp=pfsockopen("127.0.0.1", 80);
                     fputs($fp, $print_output);
                         fclose($fp);

                     echo 'Successfully Printed '.$print_output;

                 }
                 catch (Exception $e) 
                 {
                         echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                 } 
             ?>
    
      <?php
         }   

        ?>
      <?php                
        $sql2= "DROP TRIGGER ersdmmmmecv";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2); 
        $sql3= "DELETE FROM res;";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql3); 

    ?>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 1*60*1000);
        // just show current time stamp to see time of last refresh.
         document.write(new Date());
       </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a MySQL trigger to update PHP variables. If you want the values of `$f` and `$l` to update whenever a new record is inserted into your `event` table, you need to do this in PHP entirely.

Something along these lines should work (note: I did not test this myself):

```
$f = "";
$l = "";

$new_id = "id_value";

$insert = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `event` (`id`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$insert->bind_param("sss", $new_id, "value2", "value3");

if ($insert->execute() === FALSE) {
    echo 'Could not insert event: ' . $insert->error;
} else {
    // If `event`.`id` is actually an AUTO_INCREMENT column, and you don't
    // specify it in your INSERT query, use this here:
    // $new_id = $insert->insert_id;

    $select = $connect->prepare("SELECT `fname`, `Lname` FROM `user` WHERE `id` = ?");
    $select->bind_param("s", $new_id);
    $select->execute();

    $select->bind_result($f, $l);
    $success = $select->fetch();
    if ($success !== TRUE) {
        echo 'Could not update $f and $l with new values: '
             . ($select->error ?: 'No user with id: ' . $new_id);
    }
}
```

If you have multiple places in your code where you insert data into the `events` table, I would personally wrap this in a function so I wouldn't have to repeat this every time.